# Trigger sns when vpn tunnel is up or down

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I am trying to create an alarm that triggers sns topic when vpn tunnels are up or down. According to documentation from AWS I created TunnelState alarm which triggers if tunnel goes down or condition hits 0. 
[image]

Now, I want to create an alarm that triggers when tunnels are up only once. Is there a way to do this? Because if I create a condition that says trigger SNS topic when the condition is 1. It will keep that in alarm status when the tunnel comes up.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, posting a solution here might help someone in the future.

I created another notification on the same cloudwatch alarm which is for OK status. When the status is 'OK' trigger SNS topic again.

So now I have two notifications: 
One in Alarm -> hit sns topic
One in OK -> hit sns topic

The above solution works perfectly.